# tinyMCE editor not working in ipad browser

Tags: asp.net, ipad, tinymce

I have implemeted tinyMCE editor in my asp.net application and it is working in all desktop browsers but not in ipad browser.

It shows content with HTML tags.

Can any one suggest if any other editor can work?